# How can I create a DirectShow Project in VS 2010

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, directshow, directshow.net

I have Visual Studio 2010 in Win7 (64-bit) and I want to start developing DirectShow projects in C++ or C#. To be honest I don't know how can I do this in VS 2010. What is the software and libraries that I need?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DirectShow is C++ (native) API. Windows SDK contains a number of samples and you would start from there. Make a copy of a sample project, replace GUIDs with new if necessary, and this will be a start point for your project.

DirectShow Samples on MSDN: [DirectShow Samples (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375468%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

In .NET and C# in particular the only way for a beginner to start with DirectShow is to use [DirectShow.NET library](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/). The library provides one with a wrapper which mimics as much as possible the underlying native API, letting you live in .NET world and yet utilize MSDN documentation for DirectShow. It has its own well done samples to check out and start from.